# ios How to change content view color except navigation bar color

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application i would like to change color of content view not the navigation bar color
I have written like `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` but its changing whole content color including navigation bar color.

Comment: What is content view? your ViewController View?, can you explain yourself a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You could just make your `UINavigationBar` to not be `translucent`. If you are working with `Interface Builder` then you should go to your `UINavigationController`, select the `UINavigationBar` and uncheck the `Translucent` property. If you are doing this in code you can just call `self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `self.view.backgroundColor` on any view controllers you want to adopt your new colour. Setting it on the window causes the navigation bar to change colour because it has transparency and therefore you can see the window background colour through it.

I recommend subclassing `UIViewController` and setting this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Then, making all your other view controllers subclass this one. This means you don't have to write the same code for every view controller.